# Float right fixed svg in a div

Tags: html, css, svg

As the title states I want to float right my svg polyline that has position fixed. JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/krcfno9w/1/

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  float: right;
}
.nav polyline {
  fill: #F7F7F7;
  stroke: #B9D7D9;
  stroke-width: 2
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg height="50" width="500" class="nav">
    <polyline points="0,0 500,0 500,50 70,50 0,0" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: I have tried right: 0 multiple times already the svg is not supposed to go over the max-width 1200 px;

**Here is an example of how it should act like**: https://jsfiddle.net/4k7tcvqx/

Comment: You can't **wrap** text around a fixed position element...if that's what you are trying to do....you also can't float a fixed position element either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking or trying to achieve.

Comment: @Paulie_D It is pretty simple I want to align the fixed svg to the right side.

Comment: Oh...then remove the float and use `right:0`. That's it. Simple.

Comment: @Paulie_D then it goes over the 1200 px max-width it should go to the right but not over the max width

Comment: ...and what width is it supposed to be if it's under 1200px?

Comment: @Paulie_D if it is larger than 1200 px it should bo aligned to the 1200 px right not to the whole screen if lower it would follow the screen like a div would.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpfull:

```
div {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 1200px;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
      background-color: #F7F7F7;
    }

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.nav polyline {
  fill: #F7F7F7;
  stroke: #B9D7D9;
  stroke-width: 2
  left: auto;
}
```

Comment: The CSS left property does not have any effect on SVG polyline elements.

Comment: It is pretty close but it goes over my max-width 1200px

Comment: @Robert Longson Yeah, I leave it by accident

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  right:0px;
   top:0px;
  }
```